# procedure IN(variable) with array

Tags: sql, procedure

I am trying to do the following procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_images_by_id(lastids VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO tb_images (file_path,file_name, file_type,file_ref_id,file_ordering) 
SELECT REPLACE(file_path, '0_','1_') ,REPLACE(file_path, '0_','1_'),'product',file_ref_id,1  
FROM  tb_images WHERE file_ref_id IN(lastids);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

then I call it --> CALL sp_insert_images_by_id('26,60,62');

but only the 26 is inserted

how can I set a @lastids  for an array ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use split function for finding last id

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]  
(  
   @RowData varchar(MAX),  
   @SplitOn nvarchar(5)  
)    
RETURNS @RtnValue table   
(  
  Id int identity(1,1),  
  Data varchar(MAX)  
 )   
AS    
   BEGIN   
       Declare @Cnt int  
       Set @Cnt = 1  
       While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)  
       Begin  
           Insert Into @RtnValue (data) Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))  
           Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))  
           Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1  
    End  
    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)  
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))  
      Return  
    END
```

and then use code to set last ID

```
 DECLARE @lastId INT 
 SET  @lastId=( SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM dbo.Split('26,60,62',',') AS S ORDER BY id DESC)
 SELECT @lastId
```

Hope this will help .